# SQL Server Query similar to VLOOKUP logic in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Table A:**

- AccountID (PK, int, not null)
- Agent (varchar(50), null)
- AccountType (varchar(50), null)

Sample Table:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════╦═══════╗
║ AccountID ║  AccountType   ║ Agent ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════╬═══════╣
║  413393   ║  Invoice       ║  A    ║
║  417811   ║  Credit        ║  NULL ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════╩═══════╝
```

**Table B:**

- AccountID(int, not null) - This is the foreign key, and I am extracting the data from both the tables based on matching AccountID records.
- Ref_AccountID (int, null)

Sample Table:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════╦
║ AccountID ║  Ref_AccountID ║ 
╠═══════════╬════════════════╬
║  413393   ║  NULL          ║  
║  417811   ║  413393        ║  
╚═══════════╩════════════════╩
```

Description: 
If the AccountType is invoice, then there would be a Agent associated with it. From Table A, you can see that it is associated with Agent A.

**Current Output:**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ AccountID ║ AccountType ║ Ref_AccountID ║ Agent ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╣
║  413393   ║ Invoice     ║    NULL       ║ A     ║
║  417811   ║ Credit      ║    413393     ║ NULL  ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

**Expected Output:**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════╗
║ AccountID ║ AccountType ║ Ref_AccountID ║ Agent ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════╣
║  413393   ║ Invoice     ║    NULL       ║ A     ║
║  417811   ║ Credit      ║    413393     ║ A     ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════╝
```

The Agent should be displayed based on the Ref_AccountID. In this example, the Ref_AccountID is 413393, and for this AccountID in table A, the Agent is "A".

Thanks

Comment: That looks like one table to me not two.....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server query with same functionality as Excel VLookup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472517/sql-server-query-with-same-functionality-as-excel-vlookup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the answer you are seeking.  I have included a complete query.  It first joins tables A and B together, and then does a self join back to table A.  From your updated information, it appears that when a record has a null value for the `Agent` column, you want to instead use the `Agent` value corresponding to the record whose `AccountID` matches the `Ref_AccountID` of the former record with the null `Agent`.  The self join is necessary in the query because it makes this alternative value for the `Agent` potentially available in each record with a possible null `Agent` column.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT t1.AccountID, t1.AccountType, t2.Ref_AccountID,
    CASE WHEN t1.Agent IS NOT NULL THEN t1.Agent ELSE t3.Agent END AS Agent
FROM TableA t1 INNER JOIN TableB t2 ON t1.AccountID = t2.AccountID
LEFT JOIN TableA t3 ON t2.Ref_AcccountID = t3.AccountID
```

Here is a working [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6515d/3) where you can test this query with the test data you gave in your original question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. However I am getting the following error when I run the query: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int."

Comment: I think `Ref_AccountID` is of integer type. You need to convert `Ref_AccountID` to `varchar`.  `COALESCE(Agent, cast(Ref_AccountID as varchar(20))`

Comment: @Tim: Yes, it is of Integer Type.

Comment: Hi Tim, The query ran fine, but the agent field still looks to be blank.

Comment: @Pavan - Is there any empty strings in `Agent` column

Comment: @Pavan, if you have an empty string or null in the `Agent` column, `COALESCE` as I have used it will still give you an empty result.

Comment: @MM93, The main data extract has more than 10K records, and most of the values are Blank/NULL for the Agent Field. I would like to retrieve values to the Agent field based on Ref_AccountID. So in my above example, the value for Agent in my second row should display as 'A' instead of NULL

Comment: What is the logic by which you would decide to place `A` in the second record?

Comment: If you look at the value in "Ref_AccountID", it is actually the "AccountID" value in another table. So AccountID "466361" links to Agent "A".  Only if there is a value in the "Ref_AccountID" (NULL values can be ignored), then check this with AccountID and then place the value of the Agent.

Comment: Please post your full table schema.  I don't feel like I have enough to go by right now.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have re-phrased the question, and provided some information of what I want to achieve. Schema details provided. Thanks

Comment: Hi Tim, when I use the latest logic, it completely ignores the fist line and just prints the second line of my output what I used to get. And still the Agent is NULL  :  417811   ║ Credit      ║    413393     ║ NULL

Comment: I suspect that there may be a problem with your data.  I can create a SQL Fiddle if you like, but even it works this won't help you on your end.

Comment: Hi @Tim, can you please create a fiddle for me please.

Comment: I created a SQL Fiddle.  It turns out the second join should be a `LEFT JOIN` rather than an `INNER JOIN` to ensure that records with a `null` `Ref_AccountID` still are retained.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE
AccountID = 466361
```

Look here for more examples:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187731.aspx